# How to call an Objective C method in Swift that requires a runtime class as a parameter

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-runtime

I started programming in **swift** for about 2 weeks now and I still have some **Objective C** classes I would like to use in my app. One example would be calling this method from Swift:

```
+ (void)transitionFromThisVCClass:(Class<SomeProtocol>)aFromVCClass
                       ToThisClassVCClass:(Class<SomeProtocol>)aToVCClass
                    WithNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)aNav
                                WithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)aDuration
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to pass in a class type like I would have done in Objective C [SomeClass class]. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**

If I'm trying to use MyClass.self like so:

```
ASFSharedViewTransition.addTransitionWithFromViewControllerClass(
     RecommendationListViewController.self,
     toViewControllerClass: RecommendationViewController.self,
     withNavigationController: self.window?.rootViewController,
     withDuration: 0.3)
```

ASFSharedViewTransition is an objective c class that I'm trying to call from swift

I get this error:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type '(RecommendationListViewController.Type,
toViewControllerClass: RecommendationViewController.Type,
withNavigationController: $T5??,
withDuration: FloatLiteralConvertible)'
to type 'FloatLiteralConvertible'
```

Comment: Please include the actual relevant part of the code that is causing this problem (not just the error message)

Comment: The current problem is separate from the original question. But, it looks like you're missing a cast -- e.g. try `self.view.window?.rootViewController as UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foo.self`, where `foo` is the class name. For example, `MyClass.self`

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work: Cannot convert the expression's type '(RecommendationListViewController.Type, toViewControllerClass: RecommendationViewController.Type, withNavigationController: $T5??, withDuration: FloatLiteralConvertible)' to type 'FloatLiteralConvertible'